# Jersey Rest API Documentation using OpenApi

Tags: java, rest, maven, openapi, jersey-2.0

I want to view the list of jersey rest service methods in API Documentation using OpenApi.Referring this link https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-configuration. The war is deployed to weblogic , i am not able to list out my service methods when I try to access the context-root link. Getting 404 service not found.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.SampleRestProject</groupId>
        <artifactId>SampleRestProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>SampleRestProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
        <swagger.version>2.2.0</swagger.version>
        <swagger-ui.version>3.17.0</swagger-ui.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${version.log4j}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.webservices.wls</groupId>
            <artifactId>wls-soap-stack-impl</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.oracle.weblogic.security.subject</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.oracle.weblogic.security</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.bea.core.transaction</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.bea.core.utils</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.oracle.weblogic.servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- swagger dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer-v2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${lib.jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>${lib.jersey.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
    <name>SampleRestProject</name>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>discr-svc</display-name>    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>valid-users</role-name>
        <principal-name>users</principal-name>
    </security-role-assignment>
    <session-descriptor>
        <cookie-name>JSESSIONID</cookie-name>
        <cookie-http-only>true</cookie-http-only>
        <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>
    </session-descriptor>
    <weblogic-version>12.2.1</weblogic-version>
    <context-root>/lsw/dme/datamanagement-svc</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

DataManagementApplication

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class DataManagementApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public DataManagementApplication() {
           //  register(DmwCsrfProtectionFilter.class, 1000);
        register(DmwInitializationRequestFilter.class, 1000);
        register(DmwAuthorizationRequestFilter.class, 2000);
        //register(DmwInitializationResponseFilter.class, 1000);
        register(SecureHeadersResponseFilter.class, 1000);
       // register(CustomOpenApiResource.class);
       // register(AcceptHeaderOpenApiResource.class);
               packages("com.rest");
        packages("io.swagger.jaxrs.listing");
    }
}
```

was getting 401 unauthorized as RIGHT_NEEDED is not added in openApi method, so customized CustomOpenApiResource Class:-

CustomOpenApiResource

```
@Path("/myopenapi")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@RequestScoped
public class CustomOpenApiResource extends BaseOpenApiResource {
    @Context
    ServletConfig config;

    @Context
    Application app;

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Operation(hidden = true)
    @RightNeeded(ROLES_STUDYCONFIG_STUDYCONS_STUDYMANAGER)
    public Response getOpenApi(@Context HttpHeaders headers,
                               @Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws Exception {

        return super.getOpenApi(headers, config, app, uriInfo, "json");
    }
}
```

The link am trying to access to view the list: https://localhost:7003/lsw/dme/datamanagement-svc/rest/myopenapi/openapi.json
Can someone please help me find out where exactly am going wrong or if I am missing out anything.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested to know that how i made it work:-

added plugins to pom.xml to copy swagger-ui as webjar and replacer plugin to replace default token:-

```
  <plugin>
                <!-- Download Swagger UI webjar. -->
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
                                    <version>${swagger-ui.version}</version>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/swagger-ui</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Add Swagger UI resources to the war file. -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources combine.children="append">
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/swagger-ui/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/${swagger-ui.version}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>swagger-ui</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Replace the OpenAPI specification example URL with the local one. -->
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>${replacer.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <file>${project.build.directory}/swagger-ui/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/${swagger-ui.version}/index.html</file>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json</token>
                            <value>/api/openapi.json</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

To avoid java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.ContentReference com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory._createContentReference(java.lang.Object)' error downgraded swagger version:-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

added openapi.yaml under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder:-

```
prettyPrint: true
cacheTTL: 0
readAllResources: false /** Only show methods in swagger-ui that are annotated */
openAPI:
  info:
    version: '1.0'
    title: 'Rest Application'
  servers:
    - url: '/api'
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
            <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                <param-value>io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources, com.home, com.datamanagement</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

now able to access the url at

https://localhost:7003/api/openapi.yaml